# How to delete between text between two patterns using SED

Tags: sed

I want to remove all the text between TBLPROPERTIES and ); in the text file that contains the following:

```
create table1(<column list> )
TBLPROPERTIES (text1=001 );
create table2(<column list> )
TBLPROPERTIES (text2=002 );
create table3(<column list> )
TBLPROPERTIES (text3=003 );
.....
....
..
....
......
create table100(<column list> )
TBLPROPERTIES (text100=100 );
```

resulting in the following text file:

```
create table1(<column list> );
create table2(<column list> );
create table3(<column list> );
.....
....
..
....
......
create table100(<column list> );
```

Comment: You want to delete all that text? Delete the file. Or clarify if that's the relevant part of the input, and what is the desired output.

Comment: I want to delete this piece of text from a file. There are multiple 
TBLPROPERTIES (. ... )
in my file. I want to remove all of them using sed command

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis edited my question to add more clarity of what  I am trying to achieve. thanks

Comment: it seems that you want to delete the whole file.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I have updated my question with more clarity. Hope you can help. thanks!

Comment: `grep -v 'TBLPROPERTIES' your_file` should be enough. Fyi, your description is still totally inconsistent: if you _remove all the text between `TBLPROPERTIES` and `);`_ from a line like `TBLPROPERTIES (text1=001 );`, you end up with `TBLPROPERTIES);`. Instead you delete the whole line, hence my suggestion of using `grep -v`.

Answer (score 2):

This command removes all lines containing *TBLPROPERTIES* pattern from your file.

```
sed '/^TBLPROPERTIES/d' testing_sed
```

Comment: `sed  -i  '/^TBLPROPERTIES/d' testing_sed`  Add `-i` to delete in file. currently output will be redirected to `stdout`

Comment: @aleksey updated my question with more clarity. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `sed`, given your example. You just need the simpler `grep`, as in

```
grep -v 'TBLPROPERTIES' your_file > your_new_file
```

If you are happy, then you can `mv your_new_file your_file`, if you like.